# kubuntu 12.04 won't start

Tags: boot, kubuntu

I have dual boot config with kubuntu 12.04 and Windows7. My problem started this morning when I tried to boot kubuntu. Everything worked fine a couple of days ago and I have not done any mayor system configurations since then.

Choosing kubuntu options from grub gives me this screen
[image]

A couple of minutes later this screen is shown
[image]

And then it gets stuck. Have been waiting for ~5mins  without anything happening.

I have tried running fsck from recovery menu without any errors. I have also tried booting in failsafex mode which gives me "Fatal server error: no screens found".
apt-get update gives me "Duplicate sources.list entry". I have also tried fixing broken packages from recovery menu.

What should I do next?

Comment: did you install any graphics drivers before?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to have been a graphics problem. I have no idea why it occurred but this solved my issues:

Re-install graphic drivers

```
Downloaded from nvidia.com and followed instructions
Run nvidia-xconfig to generate new xorg.conf
```

Re-install nvidia-current

```
apt-get install --reinstall nvidia-current
```

Re-installed kubuntu desktop

```
apt-get install --reinstall kubuntu-desktop
```